# alternative to DATEDIFF(yyyy)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am unable to use DiffDate code such as

```
Declare @start datetime
Declare @finish datetime

Set @days = DATEDIFF(yyyy, @startdate, @finishdate)
SELECT @days/365 AS Years
```

Because I cannot find the finishdate column on the IT vendor application that has been supplied to the company I am working for. My employer does not want to pay the IT vendor for this solution.

So I was looking for alternative solution and I tried the following and it does not work...

Assume some values have been inserted and it is showing something like on the application...

```
 EmpID    startdate      finishdate     
 1        01/01/2014     01/01/2015      
 2        02/02/2014     02/02/2015    
 3        01/01/2012     01/01/2015
```

I'm getting the following output

```
EmpID   Totalyears
1           1
2           1
3           1
```

when I use the following code...

```
select EmpIDID, Count(StartDate) From Persons GROUP BY EmpID;;
```

When the output should be for Totalyears...

```
EmpID   Totalyears
1           1 
2           1
3           3
```

I am currently testing on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) which is SQL online website
Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

Can counter variable be used? something on the line of formula of 
startdate + counter

For example 
startdate
01/01/2014

and there is counter variable 
Declare
Counter int;

Comment: Show your data. SQL Fiddle link is empty

Comment: I cannot find the finishdate column - Do you mean you cannot select/see the data for that column? Is that correct?

Comment: @staticvoidmain - I cannot see the data for that column and I cannot see  finishdate column  column from the system but I can see for  startdate column. In C# you can increment counter on console or on label 1,2,3 etc. Can anything like that achieved in TSQL?

Comment: @Person-Yeah we have something called 'identity' that increments when data gets added to the record.  But for your case, you cannot even see the record from the system ( I assume you mean the server).  This seems to be some permission error or the column does not exist in the table.  Why do you need to increment some data?

Comment: @staticvoidmain - for the end user to see difference in years. Column must exist because it allow users enter startdate and enddate,  otherwise user would not enter enddate.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DATEDIFF`, don't need to divide by 365:

```
SELECT EmpID, DATEDIFF(yyyy,startdate,finishdate) AS  Totalyears 
FROM Persons;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/400474)**</kbd>

Comment: many thanks replying back to me. Unfortunately I'm unable to use finishdate because I do not know what the name of the column is. Can counter variable be used for example for row one  use  + 1.

Comment: @Person Show your fiddle with data. Now it is empty

Comment: I'm unable to use the solution you are offering. It works but as mentioned I'm unable to find finishdate column on there system.

Comment: @Person I am unable to understand your problem with sample data. You provided startdate and finishdate as sample and now you say you have different schema. Better pay your IT vendor. It will be much easier.

Comment: startdate and finishdate as sample is from the software side, where users enter details.

Comment: yes I know that but I can't authorise this. btw why mark my question down?

Comment: @Person It is unclear without schema and sample data

Comment: I have explained this couple times to my manager. I told them about what you said about schema. If there is alternative solution out there let me know. Many thanks for your help